Is there a correct way to add a text file into the spec file of pyinstaller?
I have come across a bug that I’m not that much able to fix. It has to do with the .spec file management and how to add external files/dependencies for reference. Although I add the corresponding data lines in the specification file, when I launch the application on cmd, a non-fatal warning appears, as follows:
CErrorString: Couldn't open CduErrStr_es_ES.txt file CErrorString: Couldn't create the hash map with the file  CduErrStr_es_ES.txt
I tried to add that file manually within the spec file, yet having the same problem in the report on CMD. I added a couple of lines with the actual lines of the filepath, yet having the same problem.
a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=[r'C:\Users\cetest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311'],
    binaries=[(r'C:\Users\cetest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\glaciation\cdu\dlls\CDUAPI.dll', '.'),
              (r'C:\Users\cetest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\glaciation\cdu\dlls32\CDUAPI.dll', '.')],
    datas=**[(r'C:\Users\cetest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\CduErrStr_en_GB.txt', '.'),
           (r'C:\Users\cetest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\CduErrStr_es_ES.txt', '.')]**,
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,

The only way to remove those messages is to directly put the *.txt file within the corresponding filepath. However, as I understand it, it should be disappearing while added on the specification and assigning a search path. What’s more, I tend to use the –clean option so as to delete the existing cache and hash, yet not fixing the mistake.
The Pyinstaller version used is 6.7.0 with pyinstaller-hooks-contrib == 2024.6
